# Make a multi-color circle in GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 2d, glut

I am trying to make a pie chart in glut. Is there a way that I can draw a single circle and change the color of the circle when I get to certain points? (for example i want half of the circle green and the other half red.) Or do I need to draw different colored parts individually.

Tried changing the color in myDisplay function but it did not work.
I am using the deprecated macOS version of GLUT

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#define PI 3.1415

using namespace std;

void myInit(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    gluOrtho2D(-780, 780, -420, 420);
}

void myDisplay(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    float x, y, i;

    for ( i = 0; i < (2 * PI); i += 0.001)
    {
        x = 200 * cos(i);
        y = 200 * sin(i);

        if (i == (2 * PI) / 2)
        {
            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);  // I tried changing the color here but it didn't work.
        }
          
        glVertex2i(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1366, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Odev 2");
    myInit();
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried drawing a pie slice in one color, then performing a fill inside the pie slice?

Comment: Im asking if there is a way that I dont have to draw individual pie slices. I want to draw a whole circle and when pi is equal to some value i want the circle to change color (changing to the other pie slice)

Comment: The condition `i == (2 * PI) / 2` will never be true. Also, do you really need a circle with 6000 vertices?

Comment: drawing individual slices does what you want. This code doesn't, because  the middle vertex is green

Comment: instead of `GL_POINTS` use `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` for filled circle with triangle pie slices (however center point will have the same color) or GL_TRIANGLES however you would need to duplicate some points. if you want just circumference then use `GL_LINE_STRIP` or `GL_LINE_LOOP` and as mentioned above  `for ( i = 0; i < (2 * PI); i += 0.001)` is not a good idea ... better is  `for ( e=1,i = 0.0; e ; i += 0.01){ if (i>=2*PI) { e=0; i=2*PI; } ... }` using any from above primitives will remove all gaps so no need for so many points `(0.01)` is more than enough angle step